# Tax Calculator C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to calculate taxes based on marital status, number of children under the age of 14, gross salary, and percentage of gross salary contributed to a pension fund. Everything seems correct, but the marital status, number of children, gross salary, and pension fund percentage are not able to be seen in my function taxAmount. I thought that using an ampersand (&) would make the values viewable by my other function. I cannot change the number of functions that I have, I must stick with the two I am currently working with. Does anyone have suggestions as to how I can fix my problem? The error message says that marital, children, grossSalary, and pension are not declared in the scope.

The prototypes are:

```
void getData(char&, int&, int&, int&);
int taxAmount(int);
```

My main function:

```
int main()
{
    char marital;
    int children;
    int grossSalary;
    int pension;

    int amount;

    getData(marital, children, grossSalary, pension);

    cout << "The tax amount is: $" << taxAmount(amount) << endl;


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My function to get data:

```
void getData(char& marital, int& children, int& grossSalary, int& pension)
{
    cout << "Enter your marital status. Enter 'm' for married. Enter 's' for";
    cout << " single. \n";
    cin >> marital;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number of children you have under the age of 14. \n";
    cin >> children;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter your gross salary. If you are married, enter the combined";
    cout << " income of you and your spouse.";
    cin >> grossSalary;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number of the percentage (up to 6) of your gross";
    cout << " income contributed to a pension fund.";
    cin >> pension;
    cout << endl;
}
```

My function to calculate the amount (code removed):

```
int taxAmount(int amount)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Although you haven't shown the code for `taxAmount()`, my money's on the `marital`, `children`, `grossSalary` and `pension` values being referenced there. They are not in that function's scope.

Comment: I don't see a cause for the error that you describe.  [I also don't get any errors](http://ideone.com/wo19ge) when I compile this code.

Comment: The last time I posted my full code on a question, someone told me not to post so much unnecessary, so that's why I removed it. Would you guys like me to post my full program?

Comment: What line specifically is generating the error message? Also, you may have been told not to post so much code, but you still have to include the **relevant** code. Posting the *relevant* portions of the code is different from dumping *all of* the code.

Comment: I don't really see how this works. Looking at the code, you get the inputs back to `main` with no problem, but then you call `taxAmount`, passing an uninitialized `int` to it, ignoring all the input you received. I suspect you don't show your full code here. Please, have a [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example)

Comment: @KelseyCalvert I noticed you've asked 4 questions and only accepted an answer once.  We here at StackOverflow often work hard to answer your questions and many third parties use these answers to solve their problems long after you've moved on.  I accept that my solution may not be the solution you're looking for but please at least provide feedback on how I can fix it to your needs as I tried to describe a number of approaches you could use.  And if you did use one of my solutions, please have the decency to click the grey check mark so future visitors can benefit from this learning experience

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the function signature of `taxAmount` to:

```
int taxAmount(int amount, char marital, int children, int grossSalary, int pension)
```

then that would be the best way to get the parameters into your function; or to save typing make a class with all 4 values and just pass in a constant reference to your class:

```
struct TaxRecord {
    char marital;
    int children;
    int grossSalary;
    int pension;
};
```

...

```
int taxAmount(int amount, const TaxRecord &record);
```

On the other hand, if you can't change the function signature either, then I recommend you make your 4 values file-scope instead of at the functional scope of the `main` function:

```
static char marital;
static int children;
static int grossSalary;
static int pension;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ...
}
```

You need the static keyword in C++ because otherwise your variable default to external; if you're in C you can drop the static keyword because that's the default (though see @wallyk's note below).

This assumes `main` and `taxAmount` are defined in the same `.c`/`.cpp` file.  If not, you would do something like this:

tax.hpp:

```
extern char marital;
extern int children;
extern int grossSalary;
extern int pension;
```

and in tax.cpp and only tax.cpp:

```
#include "tax.hpp"

char marital;
int children;
int grossSalary;
int pension;
```

That way every translation unit (`cpp` file) will have access to those 4 variables.  But keeping them static at file scope is much cleaner since the names don't pollute your entire executable, just the one file.

Comment: `static` at module scope in C doesn't change the storage class, but the visibility (publicness) of functions and variables.  `static` hides them.  Without `static` makes them public.

Comment: Static means the variables are isolated at file scope.  If taxAmount is defined in the same file as main, then static is fine, but if taxAmount is a different file, then yes, you need external linkage and in that case a shared header.  The implication was this was all one file.  If not, declare the variables as extern in a header and define them in main.cpp.  So @wallyk, I believe we were saying the same thing above.